# Find and highlight word starting with Uppercase letter except the first word in a string using PHP?

Tags: php

Forexample, I have a string :

> Liaqat Fayyaz delete data on module Users

I want to highlight **Users** like this.

> Liaqat Fayyaz delete data on module **Users**

Is there a way to do this using php?

Comment: explain `Uppercase letter except the first word in a string using PHP?`

Comment: Try using regex match some thing like this should work **preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]/", $search_terms )**

Comment: Sentences usually start with upper-case letter by convention. I don't want to get that, I want to get the word which is abnormally starting with capital letter in the string.

Comment: then how to highlight it? @sT0n3

Comment: Why not `Fayyaz` to be highlighted along with `Users`?

Comment: @HarisKhan Once you preg_match found any maching pattrens in the string use str_replace, some thing like this **str_replace ($matched_word, '<b>.$matchedwork.<b>', $search_terms)** that will get it bold in html view. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Narayan OP wants to highlight all the title case word except the first one.

Comment: ok @SougataBose Actually I am confuse because he has only bold `Users` in his questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in this case -

```
$s = 'Liaqat Fayyaz delete data on module Users';

preg_match_all('([A-Z][^\s]*)', $s, $matches); // match all title case words
array_shift($matches[0]); // Remove first word 
foreach($matches[0] as $w) {
   $s = str_replace($w, "<strong>$w</strong>", $s); // highlight each of them 
}

echo $s;
```

**Output**

```
Liaqat <strong>Fayyaz</strong> delete data on module <strong>Users</strong>
```

[Code](https://eval.in/819403)

[preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: I have not used the `array_shift()` but it is still working well for me.

Comment: `array_shift()` to remove the first word so that *Liaqat* does not get highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Oh its very simple find and replace with strong tag your word in php like this

```
$str = 'Liaqat Fayyaz delete data on module Users';
echo  str_replace('Users', '<strong>Users</strong>', $str);
```

let me know if have any issue i will correct it.

Comment: No this is not the thing I am asking for, the strings will change. The code should b applicable to all